# Returning a Min() and another field?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm building a leaderboard and want to return a MIN() value - however, I also want another field which is on the same row as the min value.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT u.username, MIN(timer) AS intScore, l.hashtag 
        FROM users u 
        JOIN leaderboard l ON l.users_id = u.users_id 
        GROUP BY u.username
        ORDER BY 
        intScore ASC
```

...this returns the correct MIN intScore, but not the correct hashtag.

The db looks liks this:

Leaderboard DB:

```
users_id, timer, hashtag
1, 10, TEST
2, 12, TEST
1, 20, TEST
3, 15, TEST
1, 5, LIVE
4, 20, LIVE
```

and I want the result to be:

```
users_id, timer, hashtag
1, 5, LIVE
2, 12, TEST
3, 15, TEST
4, 20, LIVE
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is this: any aggregate function "doesn't care" about the rest of its line
If it wasn't MIN but SUM, its easier to see...

The solution is a bit tricky, you should do something that involves LEFT JOIN with an inequality :

```
SELECT u.username, l.timer AS intScore, l.hashtag

FROM
 leaderboard l
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.users_id = l.users_id
 LEFT JOIN leaderboard l2 ON l.users_id = l2.users_id AND l2.timer < l.timer
WHERE
 l2. users_id IS NULL
ORDER BY intScore ASC
```

The idea is getting lowest value by skipping the MIN function and getting the entire row

Filtering by date (or any other column / criteria for that matter) from the leaderboard table, will require us to filter each table we use
It's important to filter the LEFT JOINed table at the ON conditition, otherwise we eliminate the filtering NULLs effect:

```
SET @date0 = '2018-01-01';
SELECT u.username, l.timer AS intScore, l.hashtag

FROM
 leaderboard l
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.users_id = l.users_id
 LEFT JOIN leaderboard l2 ON l.users_id = l2.users_id AND l2.timer < l.timer AND l2.game_date >= @date0
WHERE
 l.game_date >= @date0
 l2.users_id IS NULL
ORDER BY intScore ASC
```

hope it helps

Comment: Nice one! But I don't think this would return a result if there were only one database entry?

Comment: Why not ? if there is only one entry, then JOINed table will be null anyway, and you'll get the only record

Comment: I don't know, it just doesn't return a result if there is only one entry!

Comment: weird, since its left join with an inequality, in the case of 1 row it will reurn the 1 row... I need to see the tablea to check it

Comment: How would I add a date field to this? So I could look for the best scores after a certain date?

Comment: Where's the date in the table ? and it's possible, but a little trickier...

Comment: I know, I've been ripping my hair out since you gave me your solution!

The date is in the leaderboard table, called game_date (y-m-d), each entry has the game date it was played.

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment...:) (how about an upvote ? ;)) I'll try to play with my query for a solution

Comment: Your question was regarding minimal value, isn't the best score the maximal value ?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: The best score is actually the lowest score, it's a timer - so the quickest time. :)