# Query not working properly with LEFT JOIN (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm still struggling with this problem (my previous post was about that, and since I've changed the table parameters, I've got another problem):

(Some columns have changed, so it's a different problem/question, since I only have the id as field to get the last insert)

table products:

```
id  name
1   TV
2   RADIO
3   COMPUTER
```

table sales (product_id is a FK which refers to products):

```
id_sales    feedback    product_id
4           GOOD        2
5           GOOD        3
6           NICE        3
```

The query I'm using:

```
SELECT products.name, sl.feed 
FROM products LEFT JOIN (
SELECT product_id, max(id_sales), feedback AS feed FROM sales GROUP BY product_id) sl
ON products.id = sl.product_id
```

The result is:

```
name         feed   
TV           NULL
RADIO        GOOD
COMPUTER     GOOD
```

It worked for TV and Radio, but in column Computer, I must show the LAST feedback, which you can see it's 'NICE', not 'GOOD'! Using SQL function MAX(id_sales) somehow is not the solution I thought it was.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a Min() and another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348182/returning-a-min-and-another-field)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348182/returning-a-min-and-another-field/52348344#52348344

Comment: notice the duplicate question. It suggests to use join with an inequality, to get the max value and the relevant line

Comment: dbms name please?

Comment: Using MySQL as dbms.

Comment: @Max check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sub-query and left join

```
select p.name,t1.feedback from products p
  left join
    (
    select t.id_sales,t.product_id,s.feedback 
       from
    (
    select max(id_sales) as id_sales,product_id from sales  
    group by product_id 
    ) t join sales s on  t.id_sales=s.id_sales
    ) t1 on p.id=t1.product_id
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I'm trying to understand the query right now.

Answer (score 1):

The best method is `row_number()`, but that is probably not available.  So, you can filter for the most recent date in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.name, sl.feed 
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON p.id = s.product_id AND
        s.id_sales = (SELECT MAX(s2.id_sales) FROM sales s2 WHERE s2.product_id = s.product_id);
```

There are alternative methods for expressing this logic.  One big advantage of this approach is that it can make maximal use of indexes for performance.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT products.name, sl.feed 
FROM products LEFT JOIN (
SELECT product_id, rank() over (partition by product_id Order by id_Sales desc) pRank, feedback AS feed FROM sales ) sl
ON products.id = sl.product_id where sl.pRank = 1`

Does this work for you?

Comment: Some words weren't recognized in MySQL. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah I don't think it was tagged as my sql.  I don't think they support the partitioning functions the other solution provided should work